# embeding any file type related tag to editor when selecting from ckfinder in ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckfinder, ckfinder3

I need to embed any file type related tag to editor when selecting from ckfinder , but I could not do it after awhile.

for example now when I upload a video file from ckfinder and select it to add to editor , just link for the file added to editor but I need video tag or for audio file , audio tag,
if some doc type selected , link to doc file add with ability to change the text of link .

application : asp.net mvc.

OS: windows
CKEditor version: 5
Installed CKEditor plugins: ckfinder , mediaembed, videoinsert and so on ...